# android - pop up messages like whatsapp sliding style

Tags: android, android-activity, popup, popupwindow, whatsapp

I want to create pop up screen for events happening. I am using an `activity` with style `Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog` for the popup window.

Whatsapp has this thing where they "count" the messages an have a little place in the right-top corner for how many messages are there.

you can slide the message to see the next one, like so:

[image]
[image]

Is there any project out there that has that implemented in open source?

I would like to do something similar with the events, reporting and counting them.

Comment: Did you got answers ?